# How to mock callbacks with mockito correctly?

Tags: spring, kotlin, callback, mockito

I have a method like this:

```
    override fun functionToBeMocked(
    param: Param,
    onSuccess: (param: Param) -> Unit,
    onError: (param: Param, errorMessage: String) -> Unit
) {
    val response = factory.request(param)
        .exchange()
        .block()

    if (response?.statusCode()?.is2xxSuccessful == true {
        onSuccess(param)
    } else if (response?.statusCode()?.isError == true) {
        val status = response.rawStatusCode()
        val body = response.bodyToMono(String::class.java).block()
        val errorMessage = "$status : $body"
        onError(param, errorMessage)
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```

I want to test the service which calls this method with the given `onSuccess` and `onError` functions. How can I mock `functionToBeMocked()` to just return `onSuccess(param)` or `onError(param)`?

Current test:

```
@Test
fun test() {

    val failure = ParamDoc(param.id, param)
    whenever(repo.findAll()).thenReturn(listOf(failure))
    
    // This method call should just execute onSuccess() or onError depending on the testcase
    // whenever(mockedService.functionToBeMocked).thenAnswer.. (?)

    underTest.functionToBeTested()

    // verify(..)
}
```

Update: request function in factory:

```
fun request(param: Param): WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<*> {
    val client = WebClient
            .builder()
            .defaultHeader("API-KEY", config.apiKey)
            .baseUrl(config.baseUrl)
            .build()

    return client
            .post()
            .uri("/service/test")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(Dto.fromParam(param))
}
```

Comment: If this reactive, never use block() or block thread

Comment: I'm doing an API call using WebClient. As I understood here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778809/3667018 using block() is ok in this case? Is this relevant to the testing question?

Comment: Block method is not the most beautiful. Recommend: StepVerifier. See: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_testing_a_scenario_with_stepverifier

Comment: Ok thank you I will look into that. However, do you have any recommendation regarding the mocking? I want to mock functionToBeMocked so it calls onSuccess or onError without making the actual WebClient call

Comment: Because u a using Kotlin, you can use https://mockk.io/ or Spring support via https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/springmockk. Other actions like Mokito.

Comment: If you would like to mock the method and use the implementation in the same instance, use Sky(K), and you won't mock all methods of class.

Comment: Could you provide an easy example (pseudo code is fully sufficient) to do that with Mockito? I dont really want to use the implementation. My service underTest A calls mockService B with the function functionToBeMocked with the onSuccess and on Error functions as a parameter. I want that mockService.functionToBeMocked just calls onError or onSuccess when invoked by serviceUnderTest A. Is this possible or the wrong approach?

Comment: I will create an example GitHub repository today after work.

Comment: https://github.com/Numichi/stackoverflow-how-to-mock-callbacks-with-mockito-correctly/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/com/example/example/ExampleApplicationTests.kt

Comment: Thanks a lot! Would it also be possible to "just" mock the function of Service B (request()) to return (or invoke) the the onSuccess or onError function which is passed as parameter bei Service A (underTest?). Then I would not have to mock the webclient.

Comment: like whenever(serviceB.request(any()(param1), any() (onSuccess()), any() (onError())).thenReturn(onSuccess(param1)

Comment: I didn't mock webclient on my solution. Just, I mocked what called, so emulated a remote endpoint like another endpoint of service. If you would like to mock method of service, you can call like `every { service.method(any(), any(), any()) } returns onSuccess("...")` just result is Unit if see my solution. So what would you like to check?

Comment: ofc, if it result anything, a `method` will give what you configured in mock

Comment: Service underTest defines the onSuccess() and onError() function. How would I mock serviceB.request(param1, onSuccess(), onError()) to just return/call onSucess(param1) or onError(param1)?

Comment: Just as you would mock any method. I will make another commit on GitHub example project after work. I will create about 6pm by UTC timezone.

Comment: https://github.com/Numichi/stackoverflow-how-to-mock-callbacks-with-mockito-correctly/blob/main/src/test/kotlin/com/example/example/MethodMockExampleTest.kt

Comment: Thanks again! That is almost what I had in mind! Since the onTestService() provides the onSuccess() and onError() functions which also have some logic, it would be great if the mock could use the functions which are given as parameters. So underTest calls exampleService.exampleMethod(param: Param, onSuccess(Param), onError(Param)), the mock then just returns on e.g. onSuccess(param) or onError(param). You are helping me a lot, thanks again.